# How do I tell snapcraft to run my code as python2 not python3 when using the new python plugin?

Tags: python, snap

Snapcraft kept telling me that the python2 plugin was depreciated and that I should be using python instead. So I changed my snapcraft.yaml to use "plugin: python" but now it's trying to interpret the python2 code as python3. Can anyone tell me how to let the python plugin know that I wish to run the code as python 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `snapcraft help python`:

> The python plugin can be used for python 2 or 3 based parts.
>
> It can be used for python projects where you would want to do:
>
> - import python modules with a requirements.txt
> - build a python project that has a setup.py
> - install packages straight from pip
>
> This plugin uses the common plugin keywords as well as those for >"sources".
>   For more information check the 'plugins' topic for the former and the
>   'sources' topic for the latter.
>
> Additionally, this plugin uses the following plugin-specific keywords:
>
> - requirements:
>      (string)
>      Path to a requirements.txt file
> - constraints:
>      (string)
>      Path to a constraints file
> - process-dependency-links:
>      (bool; default: false)
>      Enable the processing of dependency links.
> - python-packages:
>      (list)
>      A list of dependencies to get from PyPi
> - python-version:
>      (string; default: python3)
>      The python version to use. Valid options are: python2 and python3

That last option (`python-version`) is the one in which you're probably interested.

Comment: Ah - the instructions! Why didn't I think of that? Thanks, adding python-version to the snapcraft.yaml solved my problem.